# Jquery check if each element's child exist, change specific element's css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

It's the first time to ask a question through stackoverflow.
I hope someone can help to solve this problem.

my purpose is hide X picture when Y picture is exist in each review area.
kind of widget code I only possible to input custom CSS and js.

I tried like below with jquery, but i think it's wrong.
Please, help to solve this problem.

```js
    /*$('#pd-review-list .widget_w .widget_item').each(function(index) {
        // index has the count of the current iteration
        var foo = this;
        console.log( foo );
        var zoo = $(foo).find('.widget_item_tab_2_photo > img');
        console.log(zoo);
        if(zoo.length === 1) {
            $('.widget_item > .widget_item_product').css('display', 'none');
        }
    });*/

    if($('.widget_w .widget_item > .widget_item_tab_2_photo > img').next('img').length > 0) {
        $('.widget_item > .widget_item_product').css('display', 'none');
    } else {
        $('.widget_item > .widget_item_product').css('display', 'block');
    };
    // if each .widget_w .widget_item > widget_item_tab_2_photo > img tag exist = in that element's .widget_item > .widget_item_product css change display: none
```

```css
    .widget_item_product {
        height: 300px;
        width: 300px;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="widget_w">
    <div class="widget_item" id="review_normal_8875193" value="8875193">
        <div class="widget_item_product" style="background-image:url('https://akuo.ai/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/placeholder.png')" onclick="redirect_to_product('23')"></div>
        <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;flex-grow:1;width:1px;" class="widget_item_size">
            <div class="widget_item_tab_1 widget_item_tab_1_2">
                <div style="margin-right:10px;display:flex;justify-content: flex-start;"></div>
                <div style="color: #777777;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="widget_item_tab_1 widget_item_tab_1_1">
                <div class="widget_item_username">
                    <span class="widget_item_username_1">NAME </span><span class="widget_item_username_2">네이버 페이 ***</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="widget_item_tab_2">
                <div class="widget_item_tab_2_text" onclick="review_more_11924()">
                    <div class="widget_item_content"><p>Lorem Ipsum</p></div>
                    <span class="widget_item_more_button widget_item_more_button_1">더보기 <i class="la la-angle-down"></i></span>
                    <span class="widget_item_more_button widget_item_more_button_2">접기 <i class="la la-angle-up"></i></span>
                </div>
                <div class="widget_item_tab_2_photo" onclick="review_detail_11924(8875193)"></div>
                <div style="flex-grow:0"></div>
                <div class="widget_item_date">2021년 1월 28일</div>
                <div class="widget_item_tab_2_etc">                    <!-- 20/08/11 수정중 -->
                    <div class="widget_item_etc" value="8875193"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="widget_item" id="review_normal_8875194" value="8875194">
        <div class="widget_item_product" style="background-image:url('https://akuo.ai/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/placeholder.png')" onclick="redirect_to_product('23')"></div>
        <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;flex-grow:1;width:1px;" class="widget_item_size">
            <div class="widget_item_tab_1 widget_item_tab_1_2">
                <div style="margin-right:10px;display:flex;justify-content: flex-start;"></div>
                <div style="color: #777777;">
                    <i class="la la-camera" style="margin-right:10px; margin-left:10px; font-size:18px"></i></div>
            </div>
            <div class="widget_item_tab_1 widget_item_tab_1_1">
                <div class="widget_item_username">
                    <span class="widget_item_username_1">NAME </span><span class="widget_item_username_2">winsh***</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="widget_item_tab_2">
                <div class="widget_item_tab_2_text widget_item_collapse" onclick="review_more_11924()">
                    <div class="widget_item_content"><p>Lorem Ipsum</p></div>
                    <span class="widget_item_more_button widget_item_more_button_1">더보기 <i class="la la-angle-down"></i></span>
                    <span class="widget_item_more_button widget_item_more_button_2">접기 <i class="la la-angle-up"></i></span>
                </div>
                <div class="widget_item_tab_2_photo" onclick="review_detail_11924(8875194)">
                    <img class="widget_item_photo widget_item_photo_s lozad" data-src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/ui-image-placeholder-wireframes-apps-260nw-1037719204.jpg" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/ui-image-placeholder-wireframes-apps-260nw-1037719204.jpg" data-loaded="true">
                    <img class="widget_item_photo widget_item_photo_s lozad" data-src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/ui-image-placeholder-wireframes-apps-260nw-1037719204.jpg">
                    <img class="widget_item_photo widget_item_photo_s lozad" data-src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/ui-image-placeholder-wireframes-apps-260nw-1037719204.jpg">
                </div>
                <div style="flex-grow:0"></div>
                <div class="widget_item_date">2021년 1월 18일</div>
                <div class="widget_item_tab_2_etc">                    <!-- 20/08/11 수정중 -->
                    <div class="widget_item_etc" value="8875194"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="widget_item" id="review_normal_8875195" value="8875195">
        <div class="widget_item_product" style="background-image:url('https://akuo.ai/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/placeholder.png')" onclick="redirect_to_product('23')"></div>
        <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;flex-grow:1;width:1px;" class="widget_item_size">
            <div class="widget_item_tab_1 widget_item_tab_1_2">
                <div style="margin-right:10px;display:flex;justify-content: flex-start;"></div>
                <div style="color: #777777;">
                    <i class="la la-camera" style="margin-right:10px; margin-left:10px; font-size:18px"></i></div>
            </div>
            <div class="widget_item_tab_1 widget_item_tab_1_1">
                <div class="widget_item_username">
                    <span class="widget_item_username_1">NAME </span><span class="widget_item_username_2">winsh***</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="widget_item_tab_2">
                <div class="widget_item_tab_2_text widget_item_collapse" onclick="review_more_11924()">
                    <div class="widget_item_content"><p>Lorem Ipsum</p>/div>
                    <span class="widget_item_more_button widget_item_more_button_1">더보기 <i class="la la-angle-down"></i></span>
                    <span class="widget_item_more_button widget_item_more_button_2">접기 <i class="la la-angle-up"></i></span>
                </div>
                <div class="widget_item_tab_2_photo" onclick="review_detail_11924(8875195)">
                    <img class="widget_item_photo widget_item_photo_s lozad" data-src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/ui-image-placeholder-wireframes-apps-260nw-1037719204.jpg" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/ui-image-placeholder-wireframes-apps-260nw-1037719204.jpg" data-loaded="true">
                    <img class="widget_item_photo widget_item_photo_s lozad" data-src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/ui-image-placeholder-wireframes-apps-260nw-1037719204.jpg">
                    <img class="widget_item_photo widget_item_photo_s lozad" data-src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/ui-image-placeholder-wireframes-apps-260nw-1037719204.jpg">
                </div>
                <div style="flex-grow:0"></div>
                <div class="widget_item_date">2021년 1월 18일</div>
                <div class="widget_item_tab_2_etc">                    <!-- 20/08/11 수정중 -->
                    <div class="widget_item_etc" value="8875195"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the goal is from your description, however I can tell you the selector is wrong as the extra `>` before `.widget_item_tab_2_photo` requires it to be a child of `.widget_item`, when it's not - it's a grandchild. `$('.widget_w .widget_item .widget_item_tab_2_photo > img')` seems to fix this issue, but I don't know if it meets your requirements.